2007 Pontiac Wave suddenly sputtering when idle (mostly just in drive)
Recent non-problem drive
A few days ago, I drove across town and back without problem. I also checked the OBD2. I didn't drive again until yesterday.
Problem description

Sputtering/vibration


Yesterday, I drove out to the middle of nowhere for a group-hike, again without any problems. Afterwards, when I turned the car on to go home, it was sputtering/vibrating (like the whole car was lurching a bit, not the muffler sputtering). Fortunately, I managed to get home.
When I was home, I shifted into different gears and observed that it was relatively smooth in most gears, with minor sputtering in forward gears, almost none in reverse, and none at all in park, with the most in drive.

Manifold shield, radiator-fan


I turned the car off and then thought to check the OBD2 again, but suddenly there was a loud grinding noise. I turned it off and popped the hood and found the metal shield over the manifold had fallen off and was lying on the radiator fan. I took it out and tried again. The sound was fixed, but the sputtering was still happening and the radiator fan wouldn't spin. (Is the heat-shield mandatory? I'm not sure how I can secure it on now that the screw-holes are rusted out.)

OBD2


Also, the OBD2 wasn't working. My phone just couldn't connect to the OBD (via BlueTooth) anymore. I thought maybe the ECU was damaged, but I should still be able to connect to the OBD2 dongle's BlueTooth (when I first got the dongle a couple of years ago, I connected it to power and tested it without it being connected to the car). I unpaired it and now I can see it in the BT device list and pair with it, but it just won't connect. I assume the dongle is borked and have ordered a new one.
Diagnostics
Today, I did some diagnostics.
I checked the air-filter and it seems okay. A bit of light black, but not overtly the problem.
I sprayed all over with soapy water but didn't notice any bubbling while checking for exhaust leaks.
There was quite a bit of steam coming from the manifold when I first turned on the engine, but I think that was the soap-water boiling off because it stopped after a few seconds.
Observations
When I checked last week, it was the same OBD codes it's had for at the last two years since I got the OBD2 dongle (and likely since we got the car seven years ago). Over the past couple of years, it has shown P0420 (low catalytic-system efficiency) and/or P0137 (low-voltage on O2 sensor). Sometimes it showed one, sometimes the other, sometimes neither, sometimes both. I assume P0137 casues P0420.
Regardless, it's been driving fine (other than non-optimal fuel-efficiency) for the last seven years (other than a couple of exhaust leaks, one from a hole in the pipes under the car, the other from the damn flex-pipe getting ripped off from a pothole or speed-bump speed-hill or something). I suppose it's possible they finally caused a bigger problem than wasting gas and I was just lucky up to now.
The temperature-gauge showed it wasn't overheated (and I didn't hear anything until after I was parked), so the shield must have killed the radiator-fan at that point, after the sputtering had already started.
It was fine while moving, it was only sputtering while idle. (I'm not inclined to try driving it right now to see if it still moves okay; I'll likely already have to waste $100 to get it towed to the mechanic from my parking-spot.) I checked the dashcam and confirmed that I had no issues while going to the hike, only after I parked on the rough back-country-road covered in rocks. 
The only other thing that was different yesterday from the previous time I drove was that I went faster on the rural-road with its higher speed-limit than the roads I drove on in town last week. But then, I've driven fast on similar roads without problem a month ago.
I looked at the engine rumbling and to my non-expert eye and random guess, it looks like it might be misfiring because of a bad spark-plug?  But I don't currently feel confident opening the cover to inspect them.
I had another exhaust-leak fixed a couple of months ago and actually observed that it was purring fairly quietly a few days ago when I was out, so ostensibly, it shouldn't be that.
Engine (and transaxle) oil dipsticks look okay to my eyes.
There seem to be no unusual smells.
Antifreeze is present in reservoir.
I don't think I can check the fuel-system (injector/pump) or the MAF or the vacuum-hoses (maybe I can try the smoke method).
Question
I'll likely need a new radiator fan (unless this can be fixed), but the sputtering definitely feels uncomfortable and doesn't seem to be related to heat. Obviously this could be multiple things, but I don't want to just bring it to a mechanic and hope for the best, I want to be able to have some sort of information to be able to call around to get quotes. (It's only been two months since I had to pay for car-repairs, it's killing me.)
So what should I ask mechanics?
Is there any other stuff I can test or information I can provide to narrow it down?

Video of engine sputtering (steam ends after soapy-water evaporates)
Engine wasn't overheated during problem

Air-filter seems okay (to my eyes)

Heat-shield fell off of manifold onto radiator-fan which no longer spins


Before you replace the fans, check the fuses. If the manifold cover jammed one or more of the fans and stalled it, that could have caused a fuse to blow.
